# Using PHP google client to get YouTube playlist (server-side oauth)

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using the `PHP Google_Client` to get the youtube playlist data on my web (a server-side Oauth ,without user check )
but get `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch` and message

The redirect URI in the request, 
    http://localhost/youtube/oauth2callback.php, 
    does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 
    Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentialsoauthclient/112609190871896620853?project=756606231401 
    to update the authorized redirect URIs.

here is the  `http://localhost/youtube/index.php` code

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setAuthConfigFile('youtube-762b39a4f0b5.json');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
  $playlists = $youtube->playlists->listPlaylists("snippet,status", array(
      'channelId' => 'UCBbOgoYXQdR-LRqrx7hdd6g'
  ));
  echo json_encode($playlists->toSimpleObject());
} else {

  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/youtube/oauth2callback.php';
  var_dump($redirect_uri);
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

here is the  `http://localhost/youtube/oauth2callback.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/youtube/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  '/youtube/index.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you added the url "http://localhost/youtube/oauth2callback.php" as a valid redirect uri for your api-key in the google api management tool?

Comment: @MartijnBots there is no way to add the URL https://ibb.co/hX5rTv  https://imgbb.com/

Comment: First picture https://image.ibb.co/byZkov/1490713686261.jpg

Comment: Second https://image.ibb.co/kVszFa/1490713785096.jpg

Comment: You can click on the client-id, "youtube (server-side oauth)" in the first picture, where you can add restrictions.

Comment: @MartijnBots clicked and go the second picture, still no way can write on the ur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screenshots, you have created a Service Account. Service Accounts use two-legged OAuth, and therefore do not have any user-consent-and-redirect dance.

A Service Account would not have permissions to videos in your personal Gmail account. Maybe that's OK, maybe it isn't. It depends on your use case which you don't describe in your question. If you need your application to act with the same permissions as your Gmail account, you'll need to use a slightly different technique. (described [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc)

Comment: this is not actually I want, but something help ,thanks